# Stop Google Photos app from deleting a local album

Tags: google-photos

I have a lot of cool projects which I like to show off when I am on the road. On my phone, I have a 'demo' album created in Google photos.

This is the single most used album on my phone, which I generally show off once per week.

The app continually deletes the local cached copies, meaning that each time I try to open my demo album, it needs to download the media from remote.

My phone has 128GB of storage, and have >100GB free.

How can I stop the Google Photos app from erroneously deleting local media?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to individually open the photos and on the options menu choose "Save to Device". This creates a copy of the photo on your device and will be stored locally for a while longer.

Another would be to visit photos.google.com on a Chrome browser, and then select the photos and download to device.

The cached photos within the Google Photos app will not stick around for long. So it's better to have the relevant photos saved to device.